# Shopify - From live site to Staging site

Tags: testing, shopify, staging

Is it possible to export a live shopify site to a staging (developer) site?
I have a live site and I want to do some changes, but I want to do it in dev mode...is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to duplicate the current live theme and make the changes in the "duped" theme. Then once you're content with your changes, you can publish the "duped" theme live.